# How do I sort items in an object in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

Built in sort and sort_by in Freemarker is for list. How Do I sort object in Freemarker?

```
<#assign myObject = {
    'item1':{'name': 'Name One', 'url': 'https://www.one.com, 'order': 1},
    'item2':{'name': 'Name Two', 'url': 'https://www.two.com, 'order': 2},
    'item3'...
}/>


<#macro displayobjectLinks>
    <ul>
        <#list objectLinks?keys as info>
            <#if (info != "item1")>
                <li><a href="${objectLinks[info].url}">${objectLinks[info].name}</a></li>
            </#if>
        </#list>
    </ul>
</#macro?
```

How do I display this in order based on 'order'?
I also need to access key of my object(item1, item2...) as I am doing something based on it.

Comment: Can you change how `myObject` looks instead? The best is if you get it already sorted of course... but apart from that, can't it be a list of objects like `[ {'info': 'item1', 'name': 'Name One', 'url': 'http://...'}, ...]`? That is, a list of objects, and each object has the properties that you need.

Comment: I can change it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**sort_by**

Returns the sequence of hashes sorted by the given hash sub variable in ascending order. (For descending order use this and then the reverse built in.) The rules are the same as with the sort built-in, except that the sub variables of the sequence must be hashes, and you have to give the name of a hash sub variable that will decide the order. For example:

In your case you can use the below code :

<#list objectLinks?sort_by("name") as info>

</#list>

Answer (score 2):

Your object is a hash, which has a [`values`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html#ref_builtin_values) built-in, which returns a sequence, which can be [sorted](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_sort). So, you could do something like:

```
<#list myObject?values?sort_by("name") as item>
</#list>
```

Please note that not all hashes support this though, but you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks! I also need to access key of my object(item1, item2...) as I am doing something based on it. Update question with it.

Comment: Beware though, `?values` isn't necessarily a sequence, it's perhaps just an `Iterable`-like value, and `?sort_by` doesn't support sorting that. Use `?values?sequence` to ensure that the value is a sequence.